# how to convert from str to list using map in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I did :

```
>>>data="1,2,3,,4,51,,6"

>>>list(map(int,map((lambda x:x.split(",")),map(lambda y:y,data.split(",,")))))
```

I want to get :`[1,2,3,4,51,6]`

Comment: Did you ask and delete the same question  previously or is this homework from some course?

Comment: this homework from python course.

Comment: Which course is it from?

Comment: principles of programming languages (in python) , in SCE Collage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to `split` the string on `','` then convert to `int` if the character isn't `None`

```
>>> [int(i) for i in data.split(',') if i]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 6]
```

If you do not want to use a list comprehension (which I would recommend), you can use `map` and `filter`, at the expense of readability

```
>>> list(map(int, filter(None, data.split(','))))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 6]
```

Comment: I want to use a map function without loops!

Comment: @AurwaYounis: why? This is the best way (list comprehension is well-optimised and you're unlikely to gain any performance benefits using `map`, as well as sacrificing readability).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` to filter empty strings and `None` values, and after that use `map`:

```
>>> map(int, filter(None, data.split(',')))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 51, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be,

```
print map(int,data.replace(",,",",").split(","))
```

Edit: This is a solution for the specific data you entered, therefore not a comprehensive method for different variety of data. Better to point out.